# Create a query with a number of columns and tables variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I have a database containing a number of tables. I also have a web-based application that is connected to it. For now I am using prepared queries.

I am trying to create a general query that will be able to take a variable number of input columns from different tables. (Basically the user checks boxes that create php variables that I need to pass to the query).

If I know that there will be let say 2 columns needed, it's easy, I only need to do something like,

```
SELECT $col1, $col2 FROM $table1 INNER JOIN $table2;
```

How can I change that so that any number of variables can be input in the query?

Thanks in advance,

Zohm

EDIT: I think I could maybe do an if/else condition in PHP or a switch and each case would correspond to a number of input columns, and each case would have its query. But this would do a lot of cases (the user could click 10 boxes for example) and It does not really seems right to do that. Moreover in the future if I need more cases I will have to change the code, which I rather not have to do.

Comment: *Basically the user checks boxes that create php variables ...* What does this mean? How are these variables related to your existing table columns?

Comment: The user has a group of boxes that he can click. Each boxes as a 2 variable name link to it, a column name and a table name (the one in the database). So if a box is checked, this 2 variables must be send to the query. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why 2 variables on a single column?

Comment: The best solution is as described in your *Edit* part of the post.

Comment: Because I don't have a single table but many. So I could do NameColumn.NameTable to use only 1 variable, but that would need to parse it before doing the FROM NameTable or INNER JOIN NameTable part of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume your form elements names are the table fields you are looking for. if this is the case you can loop through the post to build your fields table. Im not sure how you are setting a variable to have 2 values...

```
 $_POST['field1'] = "true";
 $_POST['field2'] = "true";
 $_POST['field3'] = "false";
 $_POST['field4'] = "true";

 $fields = "";
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
 {
       $fields .= $key . ",";
 }
```

which will end up with

```
  $fields = "field1,field2,field4,";
```

now you have to remove that last comma,

```
  $fields = substr($fields,0,-1);
```

so then you can:

```
    $query = "SELECT " . $fields . " from table1...and so on.
```

Comment: Unchecked items won't go to server. So `$value == "true"` comparison won't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I can work with that. If I create a dynamic array, in which I put a variable when its box is checked, I can then loop through it and do your solution of concatenation. (Seems possible at least!). This will avoid the $_POST['field1'] to field n which can be big. If I don't manage to I can still go back to your solution.

Comment: how are you getting 2 values in 1 variable?